Azure Communication Services python, how do I send a Whatsapp message with parameters
In the Meta Whatsapp Business portal you can define message templates which include parameters, for example a users name or multiple parameters.
Example: "You made a purchase for {{1}} using a credit card ending in {{2}}."
I want to send a whatsapp message template which includes parameters using Azure Communication Services. The python QuickStart shows examples on how to send a plain message template, but there's no documentation on how to include parameters. How can I do that?
Link to documentation: click

I was struggling with this as well, had to look into the source code to figure out how to bind a parameter to a message template. But here's a working version, which is an adjustment on the example from the linked documentation.
import os 

from azure.communication.messages import NotificationMessagesClient
from azure.communication.messages.models import (
    TemplateNotificationContent,
    MessageTemplate,
    MessageTemplateText,
    WhatsAppMessageTemplateBindings,
    WhatsAppMessageTemplateBindingsComponent,
)


class MessagesQuickstart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection_string = os.getenv("AZURE_COMMUNICATION_SERVICES")
        self.phone_number = os.getenv("PHONE_NUMBER")
        self.channelRegistrationId = os.getenv("WHATSAPP_CHANNEL_ID")

    def send_template_message(self, param_name_1: str, param_value_1: str):
        # Initialize NotificationMessagesClient
        messaging_client = NotificationMessagesClient.from_connection_string(self.connection_string)
        
        # Define template parameters
        param1 = MessageTemplateText(name=param_name_1, text=param_value_1)
        # param2 = MessageTemplateText(name="second", text="Second Parameter")
        
        # Define the bindings for WhatsApp template body
        bindings = WhatsAppMessageTemplateBindings(
            body=[
                WhatsAppMessageTemplateBindingsComponent(ref_value=param1.name),
            ]
        )

        # Set up the template with bindings and values
        message_template = MessageTemplate(
            name="aisha_voorselectie",
            language="nl",
            template_values=[param1],
            bindings=bindings
        )

        # Create TemplateNotificationContent
        template_options = TemplateNotificationContent(
            channel_registration_id=self.channelRegistrationId,
            to=[self.phone_number],
            template=message_template
        )

        # Send the message
        message_responses = messaging_client.send(template_options)
        response = message_responses.receipts[0]
        
        if response is not None:
            print(f"WhatsApp Templated Message with message id {response.message_id} was successfully sent to {response.to}")
        else:
            print("Message failed to send")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wa = MessagesQuickstart()
    wa.send_template_message()

